# Manual Password with hiding password field Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am using User in-built model of django. I want to create password for user like 'test@123' for everyone. without showing password field in template

register.py

```
@login_required
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ur_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        pr_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if ur_form.is_valid() and pr_form.is_valid():

            new_user = ur_form.save(commit=False)            
            new_user.username = new_user.email
            password = 'test@123'
            new_user.password = password
            new_user.save()

            profile =  pr_form.save(commit=False)
            if profile.user_id is None:
                profile.user_id = new_user.id
                profile.user_role_id = 3
            profile.save()

            username = ur_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Your Account has been created for %s!' % username)
            return redirect('users')
    else:
        ur_form = UserRegisterForm()
        pr_form = UserProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'ur_form': ur_form, 'pr_form': pr_form})
```

Forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name', 'email']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       del self.fields['password1']
       del self.fields['password2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_password` method for it. For example;

```
new_user = ur_form.save(commit=False)            
new_user.username = new_user.email
password = 'test@123'
new_user.set_password(password) # <- here
new_user.save()
```

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password);

> Sets the user’s password to the given raw string, taking care of the password hashing. Doesn’t save the User object.

Comment: It is giving me error `new_user = ur_form.save(commit=False)
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 119, in save
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
KeyError: 'password1'
`

Comment: @HuzaifSayyed, why do you use `__init__` method of `UserRegisterForm`? Just `exclude` password fields from `Form` class.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `new_user.password = password` to `new_user.password1 = user.set_password(password)`

also fix the line `new_user = ur_form.save(commit=False` to `new_user = ur_form.save(commit=False)`

remove this form forms.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       del self.fields['password1']
       del self.fields['password2']
```

**Final edit:**
in `UserRegisterForm`

```
new_user = f.save(commit=True)
new_user.password = new_user.set_password('sdfasd')
```

and in `forms.py`

```
class UserRegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', )
```

Comment: No its giving me error this |: KeyError at /users/register/
'password1'

Comment: just use `password`

Comment: KeyError at /users/register/
'password1'

Comment: use passsword1 as shown in answer. See the edited answer

Comment: if i remove `_init_` from forms.py. Then Password field is shown in template

Comment: but as I say to use `password` how it's through key error password1

Comment: `new_user.password = user.set_password(password)` Like This but still same error and even i used `new_user.password1 = password`

Comment: `new_user.password = user.set_password(password)` this?

Comment: still same error `KeyError at /users/register/
'password1'`

Comment: new_user.set_password(password) try this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185813/discussion-between-shafikur-rahman-shaon-and-huzaif-sayyed).

Comment: hello sir are you there
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm): 
email = forms.EmailField() 
first_name = forms.CharField() 
last_name = forms.CharField() 

password2 = None 
class Meta: 
model = User 
fields = ['first_name','last_name', 'email']
i used this and it is working
but now the problem is i want to remove that password field from template
can you please help me how to remove password field from template without getting key error

Answer (score 0):

I did It like this

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
   credit = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=10)

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ["email"]

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['password1'].required = False
       self.fields['password2'].required = False
       # If one field gets autocompleted but not the other, our 'neither
       # password or both password' validation will be triggered.
       self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
       self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
       self.fields['password1'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
       self.fields['password2'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanatory steps to your answers?